# Char array rotation error in C - can't see reason why

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I'm trying to rotate an array to the left, I am getting really weird results and cannot see the error, maybe I need sleep. Help will be greatly appreciated

```
int main() {

int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
char ar[n];
char temp[n];

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    scanf("%c", &ar[i]);
}
int i;
temp[0] = ar[0];
for (int i=0; i<(n-1); i++) {
    ar[0+i] = ar[1+i];
}
ar[n-1] = temp[0];

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%c", ar[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Example Input:

7
cacbbba

Example output:

cacbbb

Comment: Notice there are 8 or more characters after the number: line-feed/space, c,a,c,b,b,b,a,line-feed.  Use `printf("%d", ar[i]);` to see.

Comment: Not related to the algorithm, C strings better ends with '\0' at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consume the 'space' character that you enter after the number. You enter the space to mark the end of the firs input (number). However that space or new line character remains in the input buffer and gets consumed by the next scanf. So when you enter 'cacbbba', the actual input received by your code is " cacbbb". The quickest, although not an ideal, thing you can do is consume that extra character before the start of the second input.

Put `getchar();` just before the start of your first `for` loop.

Here's the sample working program:

```
int main() {

int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
char ar[n];
char temp[n];

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    scanf("%c", &ar[i]);
}
int i;
temp[0] = ar[0];
getchar(); //Consume the extra space or newline char.
for (int i=0; i<(n-1); i++) {
    ar[0+i] = ar[1+i];
}
ar[n-1] = temp[0];

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%c", ar[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your way is correct but you have logic mistake when reading each character `scanf("%c", &ar[i])`
`scanf` will take whitespaces in your inputs 
so when you input `7 cacbbba` it will read whitespace and save it in array as character so you will notice in your output that one character is missing.

it should be`scanf(" %c", &ar[i])` to ignore whitespaces.

also no need to use `temp[n]` char array just `temp` char variable is enough in your case.

your code should be like :

```
int main(void) {
int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
char ar[n];
char temp;

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    scanf(" %c", &ar[i]); // ignore whitespaces
}
int i;
temp = ar[0];
for ( i=0; i< n-1; i++) {
    ar[i] = ar[i+1];
}
ar[n-1] = temp;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%c", ar[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
  int main() {

int n;
scanf("%d", &n);
char ar[n];
char temp;

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    scanf("%c", &ar[i]);
}
int i;
temp = ar[0];
for (int i=0; i<(n-1); i++) {
    ar[i] = ar[1+i];
}
ar[n-1] = temp;

for(int i=0; i<n; i++){
    printf("%c", ar[i]);
}

return 0;
}
```

You can  use this code. no need to create temp array.

Answer (score -1):

Use a string for the input, flush the standard i/o.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

void rotate(char* arr, uint8_t size)
{
    printf("rotating\n");
    uint32_t last = arr[0];
    for(uint8_t i = 1; i < size; ++i)
    {
        arr[i-1] = arr[i];
    }
    arr[size-1] = last;
}

void print_arr(char* arr, uint8_t size)
{
    printf("array: %s",arr);
    printf("\n");
}

int main(void)
{

    uint8_t n;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    fflush(stdout);
    char arr[n+1]; //mallocing for the size is a bit better

    scanf("%s", &arr);
    fflush(stdout);
    n = strlen(arr); //Not the best thing to do using strlen
    print_arr(arr,n);

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        rotate(arr,n);
        print_arr(arr,n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char arr[n];  scanf("%s", &arr);` fails.  `arr[n]` is 1 too small for `"7 cacbbba"`.

Comment: You are correct, scanf automatically adds the null-terminator. Should be n+1 for the size so it keeps the null inside the array memory.

Comment: `scanf("%s"` is equally as bad as `gets`